# Implementation of printf for float in GNU C , semihosting

Tags: c, arm, printf, gnu

I need to use gnu c printf function to send floating point number to  semihosting console.
The current implementation printf(vsnprintf)  is

```
 signed int vsnprintf(char *pStr, size_t length, const char *pFormat, va_list ap)
{
    char          fill;
    unsigned char width;
    signed int    num = 0;
    signed int    size = 0;

    /* Clear the string */
    if (pStr) {

        *pStr = 0;
    }

    /* Phase string */
    while (*pFormat != 0 && size < length) {

        /* Normal character */
        if (*pFormat != '%') {

            *pStr++ = *pFormat++;
            size++;
        }
        /* Escaped '%' */
        else if (*(pFormat+1) == '%') {

            *pStr++ = '%';
            pFormat += 2;
            size++;
        }
        /* Token delimiter */
        else {

            fill = ' ';
            width = 0;
            pFormat++;

            /* Parse filler */
            if (*pFormat == '0') {

                fill = '0';
                pFormat++;
            }

            /* Parse width */
            while ((*pFormat >= '0') && (*pFormat <= '9')) {

                width = (width*10) + *pFormat-'0';
                pFormat++;
            }

            /* Check if there is enough space */
            if (size + width > length) {

                width = length - size;
            }

            /* Parse type */
            switch (*pFormat) {
            case 'd': 
            case 'i': num = PutSignedInt(pStr, fill, width, va_arg(ap, signed int)); break;
            case 'u': num = PutUnsignedInt(pStr, fill, width, va_arg(ap, unsigned int)); break;
            case 'x': num = PutHexa(pStr, fill, width, 0, va_arg(ap, unsigned int)); break;
            case 'X': num = PutHexa(pStr, fill, width, 1, va_arg(ap, unsigned int)); break;
            case 's': num = PutString(pStr, va_arg(ap, char *)); break;
            case 'c': num = PutChar(pStr, va_arg(ap, unsigned int)); break;
            default:
                return EOF;
            }

            pFormat++;
            pStr += num;
            size += num;
        }
    }

    /* NULL-terminated (final \0 is not counted) */
    if (size < length) {

        *pStr = 0;
    }
    else {

        *(--pStr) = 0;
        size--;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Any help to implement 'f' format specifier is greatly appreciated

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  If you "need to use the GNU C printf", why don't you just use it?

Comment: you could see in the code that the implementation of vsprintf does not support 'f' format specifier. That is why it can not be used as is !

Comment: At first I was going to cry foul because there's no way they'd omit that, but then I looked at the tags. You're on an arm system. No floating point. Just go look at the implementation for x86 or similar.

Comment: Do you want *correct* floating point printing, or just something quick-and-dirty? Getting it right is rather difficult and involves writing your own decimal bignum code (or using an existing library, but that's overkill since you only need one operation mult/div by powers of 2), performing correct rounding, etc. and requires at least a few kb of working space on the stack (or for single-thread embedded systems, a static work buffer would do).

Comment: @R anything will do , At this point I am not interested in precision, Thanks for asking.

Comment: You could start from http://research.swtch.com/ftoa

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a custom printf implementation as opposed to using one from libc your toolchain. Provided you have implemented [syscalls](http://www.yagarto.de/download/yagarto/syscalls.c), you should be able to simply switch to the standard printf implementation of the toolchain by simply not compiling in your stdio implementation.

Another way could be to make a PutFloat function that simply multiplies the input by a power of 10 and then separately prints the above and below decimal parts of the number using existing integer prints. For example:

```
x = (signed int)floatIn*10000;
PutSignedInt(x/10000);
PutChar('.');
ax = abs(x);
ay = abs(y);
ax = ax - ay*10000;
PutSignedInt(ax);
```

If you get the idea, you should be able to fill in the details yourself.